# Sorting XML in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, sorting

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pages>
  <page>
    <ID>8</ID>
    <subject_ID>3</subject_ID>
    <menu_name_eng>some english</menu_name_eng>
    <menu_name_ger>some german</menu_name_ger>
    <menu_name_fre>some french</menu_name_fre>
    <position>2</position>
    <location>1</location>
    <visible>1</visible>
    <content_eng>some more english</content_eng>
    <content_ger>some more german</content_ger>
    <content_fre>some more french</content_fre>
    <big_image></big_image>
    <video_upload></video_upload>
  </page>
  <page>plenty more page tags</page>
</pages>
```

And (in ReadSubject.as) I'm parsing it into AS3 with

```
public function ParsePages(pagesInput:XML):void {
    var visibleList:XMLList = pagesInput.page.visible;
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < xmlData.page.length(); i++){
        if (xmlData.page[i].visible == "1") {

            inPosition[i] = xmlData.page[i].position;
            inLocation[i] = xmlData.page[i].location;

            menuName[i] = xmlData.page[i]["menu_name_" + setLang];
            content[i] = xmlData.page[i]["content_" + setLang];

            menuNameEng[i] = xmlData.page[i]["menu_name_eng"];
            menuNameGer[i] = xmlData.page[i]["menu_name_ger"];
            menuNameFre[i] = xmlData.page[i]["menu_name_fre"];

            contentEng[i] = xmlData.page[i]["content_eng"];
            contentGer[i] = xmlData.page[i]["content_ger"];
            contentFre[i] = xmlData.page[i]["content_fre"];
        }
    }
}
```

Then (in Index.as) adding it to the stage with

```
btnHolder4.txt.text = subjects["menuName" + selLang][3]; 
btnHolder4.addChild(picLoaderTodo);
btnHolder4.x = 1470;
btnHolder4.y = 440;
addChild(btnHolder4);
btnHolder4.buttonMode = true;
btnHolder4.mouseChildren = false;
```

And what I want to do but can't get my head around is how to use inPosition to control the order the data is added to the stage. 
inPosition, inLocation, content, etc. are all arrays but I'm really quite new at this so I'm pretty lost right now.

Comment: your question is not clear, can you explain

Comment: Ok, rather than using the "3" in btnHolder4.txt.text = subjects["menuName" + selLang][3]; I would like to use the numerical value of the array inPosition to control in what order the data is added to the stage.

Comment: how many page tag do you have in your xml

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using one class for the parsing bit (ReadSubject.as) and a different one for the adding to stage bit (Index.as). Then I use `var subjects:ReadSubject = new ReadSubject();` and I actually came up with your solution before but couldn't work my way trough the errors it caused. - Number of page tags in XML is unknown as it is dynamic.

Comment: @monocular so you want to sort each "page" node by it's "location" child node.

Comment: @monocular oh I think I understand what you want now.

Comment: @Taurayi Yes I want to sort each page by the position node and then I will use the location to sort additional data that I didn't post in the  original question.  Thought I'd try to solve one problem at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, to sort each "page" node based on the value of it's "position" child node you can use a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm like in the following example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var pages:XML = 
            <pages>
                <page>
                    <position>2</position>
                </page>
                <page>
                    <position>5</position>
                </page>
                <page>
                    <position>1</position>
                </page>
                <page>
                    <position>3</position>
                </page>
                <page>
                    <position>4</position>
                </page>
            </pages>;

            sortPages(pages);

            trace(pages.toXMLString());

        }// end function

        private function sortPages(pages:XML):void
        {
            var sort:Boolean = true;

            while (sort)
            {
                sort = false;

                for (var i:int = 0; i < (pages.page.length()-1); i++)
                {
                    if (int(pages.page[i].position) > int(pages.page[i+1].position))
                    {
                        var node1:XML = new XML(pages.page[i]);
                        var node2:XML = new XML(pages.page[i + 1]);
                        pages.page[i] = node2;
                        pages.page[i + 1] = node1;
                        sort = true;

                    }// end if

                }// end for

            }// end while

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to loop through the lines of code posted above but this might actually be a much better way to do what I want to do.  So, thank you  :)

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your buttons and set the y position of your button equal to the height of the button times the position.

Comment: I don't understand how that works... Besides, I'm  planing on using variations of my code above throughout my application, for buttons and pages etc. so I think I really need to use something like `btnHolder4.txt.text = subjects["menuName" + selLang][3];` or some variation on that.  But I could be wrong of course...

Answer (score 0):

```
sortOn(xml, ["@firstName", "@lastName"]);

public function sortOn(xml:XML, names:*, options:*=0):void
{
    var i1:int;
    var ar:Array=[];
    var list:XMLList=xml.children();
    for (i1=0; i1 < list.length(); i1++)
        ar.push(list[i1]);

    ar.sortOn(names, options);
    for (i1=0; i1 < list.length(); i1++)
    {
        if (list[i1] != ar[i1])
        {
            delete xml.children()[ar[i1].childIndex()];
            xml.insertChildBefore(list[i1], ar[i1]);
            list=xml.children();
        }
    }
}
```